# calling thread access error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have 2 viewModels - one for main program and another for my user control. When I dynamically create user control, I start background thread :

```
 private void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(()=> CustomControl.ViewModel.InOperation = true);
        while (!StopMeasuring)
        {
            //some action
        }
    }
```

InOperation is property in my userControl viewModel :

```
 public virtual bool InOperation
    {
        get { return _inOperation; }
        set
        {
            if (_inOperation==value) return;

            _inOperation = value;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                                           {
                                                               InOperationEvent(ControlId);
                                                           })); 
        }
    }
```

and I send InOperationEvent to my main viewModel :

```
  public void OnUsercontrolInOperationChanged(int controlId)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
            foreach (var userControl in _allUserControls.Where(control => control.Name == _currentUcName))
            {
                switch (userControl.Name)
                {
                      //switch cases
                }
            }
        });}
```

and during runtime, on foreach loop in my main viewModel I get exception - *the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it*

Can anyone point me where I am wrong?

Thnx in advance

Comment: But I am using dispatcher and get error, and in that article there were no dispatcher. So why it's duplicate?

Comment: The solution I linked to does not use the static property `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` - it uses a Dispatcher from an instance of a UI control: `mainFrameView.Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thxn for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` returns the dispatcher for the current thread. If you call this on a background thread, you get a dispatcher for that background thread. In order to marshal back to the UI thread, you need a reference to the Dispatcher on the UI thread. You can do this by reading the value of the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` property on the main thread, and then pass that value to the background thread.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your suggestion or you missunderstood me. I don't want to pass value to background worker back. My goal is, when background worker starts, change value in userControl and from userControl fire event to mainViewModel. In mainViewModel I get this exception

Comment: Understood. My suggestion still stands. The problem is that `BackgroundWorkerDoWork` is running on a background thread. Therefore `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke()` in that method is going to attempt to invoke on the background thread (because `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` always returns a dispatcher for the current thread). The InOperation set-value call therefore occurs on the background thread, and the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke()` in that setter invokes a call on the background thread....

Comment: That means `OnUsercontrolInOperationChanged` is being called on a background thread. There's another `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` call in there, but that's just invoking on the background thread. When the `foreach` runs, it's running on a background thread. You are then attempting to call the `.Name` property of your controls, which cannot be done a background thread.